# Getting only values using a key from my dictonary that contians a list of values per key

Tags: c#

Question is how can I get only the values from my dictionary that contains one key but has a list of values assigned to it. I want to be able to grab all of the values and convert them into a tuple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Main code

```
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> v_dict_info = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> V_dict_info
        {
            get => v_dict_info;
            set => v_dict_info = value;
        }

        public static string Vista_con_s
        {
            get => _vista_con_s;
            set => _vista_con_s = value;
        }

        public void get_emp_info_addr()
        {



            string info_addr = "select " +
                                 "c.empno " +
                               "from " +
                                 "[V4].[dbo].[person] c ";
            try
            {
                vista_conn = new SqlConnection();
                vista_conn.ConnectionString = _vista_con_s;

                vista_command = new SqlCommand(info_addr, vista_conn);

                vista_conn.Open();

                vista_reader = vista_command.ExecuteReader();

                if (vista_reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (vista_reader.Read())
                    {
                        v_dict_info.Vista_addr_list("empno", vista_reader.GetValue(0).ToString());


                    }
                }


            }

            catch (SqlException sq_x)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error connecting to the database! -Error Msg: {0}", sq_x.ToString());

            }

            var count = v_dict_info["empno"].Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var empno = v_dict_info["empno"][i];


                Console.WriteLine("{0}", empno);


            }

            // how can I get only the values associated to "empno" key  
            var xx = empno //this only return the first element :( I want all of them 

            Console.WriteLine(xx.ToString());

        }
```

Here is my method for adding multiple values to one key in a dictionary.

```
public static class Multi_dict
{


    public static void Vista_addr_list<T, U>(this IDictionary<T, List<U>> dict, T key, U elementToList)
    {

        List<U> list;

        bool exists = dict.TryGetValue(key, out list);

        if (exists)
        {
            dict[key].Add(elementToList);
        }
        else
        {
            dict[key] = new List<U>();
            dict[key].Add(elementToList);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question, your dictionary has a list of strings as elements, why don't you use that list? There's no benefit to use a tuple when all the elements are of the same type if you already have them encapsulated in some way.

Comment: Okay can you show me how to go about doing it that way. @Gusman

Comment: Do you mean how to get an element from the dictionary? `var empno = v_dict_info["empno"];`

Comment: When I do that I am only able to get the list. how to get each element out of the values list? @Gusman

Comment: The list contains all the elements, you must iterate it to retrieve the values or access by it's index, exactly as you do on the `for` in your code.

Comment: `var element = v_dict_info["empno"][n]`, where n is an index of the list,.Or use a foreach loop but seriously this is the least of your problems here.  Your design is badly flawed.  Why are you using a tuple, if you using ADO then a DataRow is a tuple, use DataTable. As @Gusman said 'What are you trying to acheive'

Answer (score 0):

Presuming this is really necessary (and I agree with Gusman's comment on the question - I don't think this is really what you need), you're already half-way there.

Access the list via the key, and then select out your tuple:

```
dict[key].Select(x => new Tuple<string, string>(key, x));
```

You can find a working fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jPX0bU